# spring mvc- form submit with validation error and back button

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a simple jsp page 'page1.jsp' this page allows the user to enter some informations in a form, in this page i have a back button wich is javascript button `window.history.back();`. The submit button posts the form and displays  Page2.jsp

if the user clic back button for the first the controller shows valdation error , and back button works fine, but if the user clic more than  2 times  **the back button not work**

I  would appreciate some guidance if there is some have the same problem.

Comment: Use proper development tools; to understand what happens with javascript, for example the Chrome developer tools (see on the Internet how to use them) - you can use javascript console to understand what happens with a particular element, or to debug the javascript on the web page; to understand what happens with the validation, inspect your HTTP request (also with Chrome developer tools), see to which controller method this is mapped, and debug Java to understand why the validation fails. The "solution" would be probably some javascript code to avoid the undesirable (to you) effects you see.

Comment: the problem in back button not in validation